# iOS Facebook Interstitial Ad

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbsdk

I have a problem implementing the FBAudienceNetwork SDK on iOS. The issue is regarding the interstitial ad, which I try to present on an UIViewController, from viewDidLoad.

My code is:

```
- (void)loadInterstitial
{
    [FBAdSettings addTestDevice:@"code"];

    FBInterstitialAd *interstitialAd = [[FBInterstitialAd alloc] initWithPlacementID:@"code"];
    interstitialAd.delegate = self;
    [interstitialAd loadAd];
}

- (void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    NSLog(@"Ad is loaded and ready to be displayed");

    // You can now display the full screen ad using this code:
    [interstitialAd showAdFromRootViewController:self];
}

- (void)interstitialAd:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Ad failed to load");
}
```

The first time I present the view controller, the ad does not appear, and none of the delegate methods are called. The second time i present the view controller, the console prints the following message:

```
 [FBAudienceNetworkLog/FBAdURLSession:183 <error>] HTTP error, status=0, error=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://graph.facebook.com/network_ads_common/, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/network_ads_common/}, bytes=0, encoding=(null), url=network_ads_common/ -- https://graph.facebook.com
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem ? Thank you.

P.S. the banner ads are working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, banners working, interstitial not.
If you follow the code sample from the Audience Network Interstitial code sample it seems to produce the 183 error. (code sample from your developer account at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{yourFbAppId}/audience-network/placements/)

When following the docs link, it works.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios/interstitial/

The difference being the code sample from Audience Network > Interstitial  declares FBInterstitialAd *interstitialAd within the (void)loadInterstitial method, the sample from docs declares it as part of the class.

Hope this helps.
Cheers